# Add pdf annotation with PDF Kit in OS 10.12

Tags: pdfkit, macos-sierra, pdf-annotations

Now the latest os10.12 operating system, PDF annotation can be displayed, but now I still have a problem, I recorded coordinate information in PDFView ->mouseDragged before, and then automatically will invoke the PDFView->drawPage function, this function I will draw the NSBezierPath curve to determine the dynamic annotation bounds. but now in the process of mouseDragged has not been call the drawPage:toContext function. So I can't see the dynamic curve of adding annotation. I use the refresh method is still not invoke drawPage:toContext, only open pdf and scroll view pdf kit will invoke drawPage:toContext. I would like to know how to call this function. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I got this problem too. I found when I zoom in or zoom out, the annotation will show. But I don't know how to make it dynamic display. It seems the SetNeedsDisplay doesn't work.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868300/pdfview-setneedsdisplayyes-doesnt-work-on-macos-sierra-10-12

Answer (score 2):

PDFKit sems to be in bit of a pickle at the moment. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60440

I have had some success using drawPage:inContext: (which is a private method covered by drawPage:toContext:). Try adding drawPage:inContext: to a class extension (ARC requires all selectors to be defined) and see if it gets called.

Comment: So the [PDFView setNeedsDisplay:YES] will call drawPage:inContext:  ? But the setNeedsDisplay still doesn't redraw the view, right?

Comment: I tried to add that to the .h file, but failed. Could you please show me a sample, if possible? It will save my life ....

Comment: '@interface TSPDFPage() // TSPDFPage is my subclass, put this in the ,m file

        // undocumented method - ARC requires selectors to be defined.
        - (void)drawWithBox:(PDFDisplayBox)box inContext:(CGContextRef)context;
    @end'

Comment: It seems the -drawPage:toContext: get called after setNeedsDisplay:Yes the 10.12.1. However, the PDFView doesn't redraw still.

Comment: Hi, I found the DrawWithBox:InContent: works for my image annotation. Thanks a lot. However the PDFView cannot redraw after setNeedsDisplay: . It seems there is a bug here.

Comment: I even tried to use the BezierPath to draw on PDFView, but failed.

Comment: I note that when DrawWithBox:InContent:  is called [NSGraphicsContext currentContext]; can be nil (I don't think it used to be). Objects cut as NSLayoutManager require a non nil [NSGraphicsContext currentContext] in order to function. Might be worth checking.

Comment: Earlier  OS (0S10.11),If setNeedsDisplay:YES will invoke PDFView->drawPage:InContent, but in OS10.12, there can't invoke.