# how to add image annotation in PDFKit in iOS11

Tags: pdf, annotations, ios11

I am using PDFKit in iOS11 to develop a app which can show pdf file add annotations. Now I want to add an image annotation to the pdf page, I think the annotation subtype should be stamp. But in PDFKit I cannot find the property like "`image`" to set, the only property related to stamp annotation is `stampName`. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I managed to do it.
The idea is to override the draw() function to do the bidding of the now absent PDFAnnotationStamp class (I found some obsolete doc about different kind of PDFAnnotation subclasses [that are now gone](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60440)).
This problem [doesn't seem to be recent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784953/add-pdf-annotation-with-pdf-kit-in-os-10-12), and the dev boards are really empty iOS side, it's almost scary.

```
public class ImageAnnotation: PDFAnnotation {

    private var _image: UIImage?

    public init(imageBounds: CGRect, image: UIImage?) {
        self._image = image
        super.init(bounds: imageBounds, forType: .stamp, withProperties: nil)
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override public func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, in context: CGContext) {
        guard let cgImage = self._image?.cgImage else {
            return
        }
       let drawingBox = self.page?.bounds(for: box)
       //Virtually changing reference frame since the context is agnostic of them. Necessary hack.
       context.draw(cgImage, in: self.bounds.applying(CGAffineTransform(
       translationX: (drawingBox?.origin.x)! * -1.0, 
                  y: (drawingBox?.origin.y)! * -1.0)))
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, actullay I find the solution but forget to post it, will accept it.

Comment: Your answer is excellent. The little hack at the end was the only way to get the stamp to appear within the original bounds when the PDF was resized or cropped. Thank you!

Comment: Working perfectly!